# Azure - Create disk from a VHD blob that is larger than 4TB

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-managed-disk

I know I can create a managed disk from a Blob VHD.

However, my blob VHD is 4TB large (4095GB).

And then the console says:

```
The source blob's size must be 20 MiB - 4095 GiB.
```

Now my question is, is there a workaround that I can create the disk from this Blob?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use azure powershell to create it, refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-windows-powershell-sample-create-managed-disk-from-vhd).

**Sample**:

```
#Provide the subscription Id where Managed Disks will be created
$subscriptionId = 'yourSubscriptionId'

#Provide the name of your resource group where Managed Disks will be created. 
$resourceGroupName ='yourResourceGroupName'

#Provide the name of the Managed Disk
$diskName = 'yourDiskName'

#Provide the size of the disks in GB. It should be greater than the VHD file size.
$diskSize = '128'

#Provide the storage type for Managed Disk. PremiumLRS or StandardLRS.
$storageType = 'PremiumLRS'

#Provide the Azure region (e.g. westus) where Managed Disk will be located.
#This location should be same as the storage account where VHD file is stored
#Get all the Azure location using command below:
#Get-AzureRmLocation
$location = 'westus'

#Provide the URI of the VHD file (page blob) in a storage account. Please not that this is NOT the SAS URI of the storage container where VHD file is stored. 
#e.g. https://contosostorageaccount1.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/contosovhd123.vhd
#Note: VHD file can be deleted as soon as Managed Disk is created.
$sourceVHDURI = 'https://contosostorageaccount1.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/contosovhd123.vhd'

#Provide the resource Id of the storage account where VHD file is stored.
#e.g. /subscriptions/6472s1g8-h217-446b-b509-314e17e1efb0/resourceGroups/MDDemo/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/contosostorageaccount
#This is an optional parameter if you are creating managed disk in the same subscription
$storageAccountId = '/subscriptions/yourSubscriptionId/resourceGroups/yourResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/yourStorageAccountName'

#Set the context to the subscription Id where Managed Disk will be created
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId

$diskConfig = New-AzureRmDiskConfig -AccountType $storageType -Location $location -CreateOption Import -StorageAccountId $storageAccountId -SourceUri $sourceVHDURI
 
New-AzureRmDisk -Disk $diskConfig -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DiskName $diskName
```